# Setting cookie properly in fuel requests

Tags: android, cookies, fuel

I'm trying to set cookie to all get or post request after successful authentication. The authentication request returns response with `Set-cookie` header value of format

```
[accesstoken=sample_token; Version=1; Comment=secured; Domain=test.com; Max-Age=172800000; Expires=Mon, 07-Apr-2025 10:55:18 GMT; Path=]
```

For web application I don't have to set anything, the xhr request automatically handles appending cookie. This cookie is also responsible for identifying user on back-end. I've read somewhere that cookie is just header with `Cookie` as key value.So after successful authentication, the `Set-Cookie` header is being read from response header of the format given using

```
var cookeis = response.headers.get("Set-Cookie").toString()
```

Next this value is appended as header in each subsequent requests.

```
fun _POST(ctx: Context, path: String, query: List<Pair<String, String?>>): Request {
  var fuel = Fuel.post(ctx.getString(baseID)+path, query)
  val accesstoken = getCookie(ctx)

  when(accesstoken!=null){
    true ->  fuel = fuel.set(com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.Headers.COOKIE,accesstoken)
    false -> {}
  }
return fuel
}
```

I can see the header being sent if I print headers in any post request as given below

```
val (request, response, result) = _POST(this@MainActivity, getString(R.string.API_MY_DATA), listOf("date" to currentDate))
                .also { println(it.headers.toString()) }
                .response()
```

this will print the same cookie previously set -

```
[accesstoken=sample_token; Version=1; Comment=secured; Domain=test.com; Max-Age=172800000; Expires=Mon, 07-Apr-2025 10:55:18 GMT; Path=]
```

but the server returns 400 response status. The same api was also used to develop an app using `react-native` library. There, xhr requests automatically handles cookie management.

NB: I don't have access to back-end.

Answer (score 0):

I got this code to work for sending a single incoming cookie:

```kotlin
// response being from a previous Fuel POST
val cook = response.headers["Set-Cookie"].first()

Fuel.get("https://mundraub.org/node/add/plant").header(Headers.COOKIE to cook)
.responseString { request2, response2, result2 ->  ...  }
```